# Vertically align different-height paragraphs to the bottom of a div?

Tags: css

[Here's my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/mZj3s/)

What I'm trying to achieve is for all the paragraphs to be vertically aligned along the bottom of the div. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are setting multiple paragraphs in a row. Try making them inline-block and using vertical-align: bottom;

Depending on how close your paragraphs are you may need to assign a negative value to the letter-spacing between the paragraphs and reset for the paragraph it self.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it looks like what you expected, but I've managed to do it using this:

```
.wrapper p {
width: 140px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 160px 0 0;
background: black;
color: white;
display:table-cell; 
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

I just removed the `float` and added the `display:table-cell;` and the `vertical-align:bottom;`.

And here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smBhC/).